# How to parse a PostgreSQL Numeric type to Rust-native ones upon request?

Tags: postgresql, rust, types, traits

Relevant code is this:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, Utc}; // 0.4.10
use postgres::{Client, NoTls, Config, types::{FromSql, Type}};
//...
for row in client.query("SELECT * FROM pricetable;", &[])? {
    let time:DateTime<Utc> = row.get(0);
    let price:i64      = row.get(1);

    println!("found datum:  {:?}", &row);
    println!("found datum: {} {} ", time, price);
}
```

The error I'm getting when I run this is thus:

```bash
thread 'main' panicked at 'error retrieving column 1: error

deserializing column 1: cannot convert between the Rust type `i64` 

and the Postgres type `numeric`', /home/me/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-postgres-0.7.6/src/row.rs:151:25
```

where `price` is a `NUMERIC` type in terms of SQL types. I can't seem to parse it into any of the standard rust types like `u64`,`i64` etc. given that they don't seem to implement `FromSql` trait that the [`postgres`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/) crate exports. (I realize it's stated plainly [here](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/trait.FromSql.html#types) that they it is, but that's not what my error says. Do i need to enable some feature? `Cargo.toml` has `postgres={version="0.19.3",features= ["with-chrono-0_4"]}`)

I've seen people recommend declaring your own wrapper type like `struct Float64(u64)` and implementing [`ToSql`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/types/trait.ToSql.html) and [`FromSql`](https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html) on those.. Is that the only way to get data out of Postgres into Rust? Is there a reference implementation if so?

Comment: What's the error you're getting? `FromSql` is implemented for i64. https://docs.rs/postgres/latest/postgres/types/trait.FromSql.html#impl-FromSql%3C%27a%3E-for-i64

Comment: Besides the point of the question, since you suggested something to that tune: Never *ever* represent a `NUMERIC` in general and prices in particular as a ´float`.  Ever.

Comment: @user2722968 what kind of type do you suggest?  
Added the detailed error. I must be getting something wrong here given that @Dogbert mentions that `FromSql` is implemented for `i64`

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [`decimal`](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/latest/rust_decimal/) instead of the native data types: it impements `FromSql` and `ToSql` which are not in fact implemented for regular rust's numerical types and SQL's `NUMERIC`. This is due to `NUMERIC` being of arbitrary precision.

Comment: don't forget to add the `db-postgres` feature. So sth. like: `rust_decimal = { version = "1.32", features = ["db-postgres"] }` from the Cargo.toml file